# Change X,Y and Z axis at (0,0,0) in Scatter 3D plot using Plotlyexpress

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I wish to plot a 3D scatter plot using **plotly.express** and wish to fix the **X,Y and Z axis at (0,0,0)** rather than the **minimum value**. I tried with matplotlib and changed the ylim and xlim but there is no such options in Plotly.express.

Can someone please help me achieve the above?

I am attaching a sample dataset and other required details.
[image: Sample Dataset with 3 numerical columns]
[image: This is a scatter plot but the axis is at minimum]

I need to **replace the -200 at each axes with 0**.

**Code:**

import plotly.express as plt
plt.scatter(x="X",y="Y",data_frame=data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting 3D axes is accomplished by specifying a range of x, y, and z axes for the scene in Layout Change. See the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/3d-axes/#range-of-axes).

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='X', y='Y', z='Z')

fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  height=600,
                  width=600,
                  scene=dict(
                      xaxis = dict(nticks=6, range=[0,300],),
                      yaxis = dict(nticks=6, range=[0,500],),
                      zaxis = dict(nticks=6, range=[0,500],)
                  )
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]